# What would be the Equivalent of following code in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2

What would be the Equivalent of following code in Python ? 
More specifically looking for Equivalent of HttpEntity in Python. Rest of it I have it figured out. I am using the urllib2 python module.

```
String checkInUrl = serverURL+"resources/slmservices/fcs/commit"; 
URIBuilder checkInBuilder = new URIBuilder(checkInUrl.replace(" ", "%20"));
URI checkInUri = checkInBuilder.build();

checkinTicket = "sdfsfsdfsfsfweafdaewfw"        
HttpEntity checkInReqEntitiy = new StringEntity(checkinTicket);
HttpRequestBasecheckInRequest=reMethod.getRequest(checkInUri,checkInReqEntitiy);

checkInRequest.addHeader("ticket", ticket);

HttpResponse checkInResponse = httpclient.execute(checkInRequest);

HttpEntity checkInResponseEntity = checkInResponse.getEntity();

StatusLine checkInResponseStatus = checkInResponse.getStatusLine();
```

Comment: Equivalent Python Code ..which errors out with http error code 405:

Comment: url = servlet_url + "resources/slmservices/fcs/commit"
headers = {"ticket":ticket,"Cookie":cookie}
checkinTicket = checkinTicket.strip().replace(" ","%20")
checkin_encoded = checkinTicket
request = urllib2.Request(url,data=checkin_encoded,headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print 'Response data', response.read()

Answer (score 0):

It seems analogous to urllib2.Request:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

Comment: Will the checkInReqEntitiy = new StringEntity(checkinTicket); go in as data parameter for urllib2.Request ? I have posted teh equivalent code above but end up with http error 405